# Are questions about usage of entertainment system features on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, site-definition

My car has an entertainment system which includes the ability to display pictures alongside the media information.  I'd like to know what the limitations on file size and/or image dimensions are for these pictures, but I'm having a hard time finding the information online.

Given proper specifics, would this be a good place to ask?  Or is there (or not) a more appropriate SE site for such a question?

Comment: FWIW, I have proposed a Car Audio Q&A on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/54656/crank-it-up?referrer=VgkbVkl5z8Az7YCC8EaVww2), This site is great but I get the feeling the Car Audio & Media Center questions would be off topic here.

Answer (score 7):

I believe if your question is related to installation or repair of an entertainment system into a vehicle then it would be on topic.

If the question is related to buying advice or operation of the entertainment system that would be off topic.

Comment: The question here would be about operation of it.  Is there a more appropriate SE site or proposal for this that you know of?

Comment: +1 If it's broken and needs fixing, maybe.  If not, maybe not.